# MongoDB & Java Driver: Range Query

Tags: java, mongodb

I have a database of documents that all contain a numerical field `X`.  I am attempting to write a query that returns a specified number of documents whose `X` fields are closest to a given value `Y`.

e.g.
List of `X` documents is `[1, 4, 9, 2, 5, 4, 6, 8, 9, 10, 23, 2]`
`Y` is 5, specified number of results to return is 6
would return `[4, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9]`

My initial thought is to get all of the documents, sort the result set by `X`, and trim the excess entries around `Y`.  I'm not sure how to implement this "trimming" functionality in Mongo, however.

How can I go about crafting a query using the Java driver that does this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing where MongoDB would help you. You have to implement such a filtering on the application level or perhaps use Map-Reduce but the standard client-side query API does not help you here (unlikely that you could implement something like that using SQL).